# supervisord: is it possible to redirect subprocess stdout back to supervisord?

Tags: docker, supervisord, coreos

I'm using supervisord as the entry point for Docker containers as described in https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/,
I want all logs to be written to stdout so I can take advantage of builtin tools like `docker logs` or systemd's journal, especially if running the containers on CoreOS.

for stderr there's `redirect_stderr=true` option for subprocesses,
is it possible to redirect the subprocess stdout back to supervisord somehow and not deal with actual log files ?

Comment: As supervisor is a daemon, I'm not sure "stdout" has any real meaning - it is not attached to a terminal or anywhere useful. Nor would anything receiving the output be able to distinguish which output came from which sub-process, which would severely limit its usefulness. Perhaps what you actually need is a way of piping each output to a command, perhaps using named pipes (FIFOs)?

Comment: actually, if its used as the entry point for a Docker container its running in the foreground

Comment: Hm, possibly. The point about all the outputs being merged together stands, though. It seems like the real question is "can I make supervisor child processes log to service X rather than a file?"

Comment: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman is actually doing a pretty good job in merging the logs to stdout, the problem with it is that its not meant to be run in production and it doesn't handle restarts of child processes if they crash

Answer (score 7):

You can redirect the program's stdout to supervisor's stdout using the following configuration options:

```
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Explanation:

- When a process opens `/dev/fd/1` (which is the same as `/proc/self/fd/1`), the system actually clones file descriptor #1 (stdout) of that process. Using this as `stdout_logfile` therefore causes `supervisord` to redirect the program's stdout to its own stdout.
- `stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0` disables log file rotation which is obviously not meaningful for stdout. Not specifying this option will result in an error because the default value is 50MB and supervisor is not smart enough to detect that the specified log file is not a regular file.

For more information:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/08/supervisord-redirecting-stdout.html

Comment: `redirect_stderr=true` is also really useful here (redirects the stderr into stdout on the program)

Comment: Unfortunately on Linux 4 Tegra this gives `spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'ssh-forward_00': ENXIO` for me. Couldn't find a workaround.