# Docker Compose - How to execute multiple commands?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to do something like this where I can run multiple commands in the following code:

```yaml
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py migrate
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

How could I execute multiple commands?

Answer (score 1464, accepted):

Figured it out, use **`bash -c`**.

Example:

```
command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Same example in multilines:

```
command: >
    bash -c "python manage.py migrate
    && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Or:

```
command: bash -c "
    python manage.py migrate
    && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  "
```

Comment: @Pedram Make sure you are using an image that actually has bash installed. Some images may also require a direct path to bash e.g. `/bin/bash`

Comment: If there is no bash installed you could try sh -c "your command"

Comment: Make sure you wrap your commands in quotes when passing to bash and I had to slip a "sleep 5" to ensure the db was up, but it worked for me.

Comment: Alpine-based images actually seem to have no bash installed - do like @Chaoste recommends and use `sh` instead: `[sh, -c, "cd /usr/src/app && npm start"]`

Comment: Can also use just `ash` on alpine :)

Comment: seems commands are separated by &&. in this case if one of my commands include a '&' sign like nohup. this will not work.

Comment: toke/mosquitto also has bash but I'm failing to do the same thing, `command: [bash, -c, "echo something > something"]` it just keep restarting and it doesn't present any log. Ps: Comporser Ver. 3

Comment: For me  `bash -c` did not work but using `/bin/bash -c` worked !

Comment: I use `sh -cx` so i can also see the commands running. useful for debugging.

Comment: The problem with these is that the command doesn't fail if any of the constituent commands fail. It always returns 0.

Comment: when trying the multiline approach, i got the error `yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a quoted scalar` .  So I kept it all on one line, but it was ugly...

Comment: What does `-c` mean?

Comment: Is this just in Python3, or even in general: I have to drop the suffix ".py" and thus run with `python3 -m main`, else I get `/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'main.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'main' while trying to find 'main.py'). Try using 'main' instead of 'main.py' as the module name.`

Comment: @Divelix If I'm not mistaken, `-c` takes the next argument as a command, executes it and then exists the shell. In regard to what Florian Loch mentioned about Alpine, I believe it's always better to use the generic `sh` than `bash` unless you're running some Bash-specific commands because `sh` (or `/bin/sh` if $PATH is not configured) is present in almost all images, whereas `bash` may or may not be.

Comment: Using this worked for me on Amazon Linux 2 with Docker Compose.

Comment: I suggest using `exec` in front of the last command. That way it gets the PID 1 and can receive signals to stop cleanly and fast.

Answer (score 279):

I recommend using `sh` as opposed to `bash` because it is more readily available on most Unix based images (alpine, etc).

Here is an example `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

This will call the following commands in order:

- `python manage.py wait_for_db` - wait for the DB to be ready
- `python manage.py migrate` - run any migrations
- `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` - start my development server

Comment: Personally this is my favourite, and cleanest, solution.

Comment: Mine too. As @LondonAppDev points-out, bash isn't available by default in all containers to optimize on space (e.g., most containers built on top of Alpine Linux)

Comment: I had to escape the multiline && with a \

Comment: @AndreVanZuydam hmmm that's strange, I didn't need to do that. Did you surround with quotes? What flavour of docker are you running?

Comment: What does the `>` do in the first line?

Comment: @oligofren the `>` is used to start a multi-line input (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3790497/2220370)

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, cleanest and something you can reason about.

Comment: Any thoughts why I would be getting. "Error: Unknown Command "sh"" even though if I remove the command from docker-compose, start up the service, I can connect to the container and execute sh

Comment: @dade strange, which image are you using?

Comment: @LondonAppDev has it all resolved. It had to do with the way the "exec" was being called in the entrypoint script, which made it impossible to tag in more commands to it. Once I updated that I was able to use the command in the docker-compose

Comment: How can we get the output of a command executed this way?

Comment: @JonathP how do you mean? In Docker the output is printed automatically.

Comment: @LondonAppDev: Yes.  I had made the mistake of having several lines with "command" and was wondering why it was not printing anything... Thx for the confirmation.

Comment: Thank, worked fine, I use the next solution:
```command: sh -c "apk add bash && /wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- echo -----5432 IS UP-----"
```

Comment: I got sh: 3: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected

Answer (score 241):

I run pre-startup stuff like migrations in a separate ephemeral container, like so (note, compose file has to be of version '2' type):

```yaml
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  image: app
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
  depends_on:
    - migration
migration:
  build: .
  image: app
  command: python manage.py migrate
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  links:
    - db
  depends_on:
    - db
```

This helps things keeping clean and separate. Two things to consider:

1. You have to ensure the correct startup sequence (using depends_on).
2. You want to avoid multiple builds which is achieved by tagging it the first time round using build and image; you can refer to image in other containers then.

Comment: This seems like the best option to me, and I would like to use it. Can you elaborate on your tagging setup to avoid multiple builds? I would prefer to avoid extra steps, so if this needs some, I might go with `bash -c` above.

Comment: In the yaml above, the build and tagging happens in the migration section. It's not really obvious at first sight, but docker-compose tags it when you specify the build AND image properties - whereby the image property specifies the tag for that build. That can then be used subsequently without triggering a new build (if you look at web, you see it has no build but only an image property). Here's some more details https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Comment: While I like the idea of this, the problem is that depends_on only ensures they start in that order, not that they are ready in that order.  wait-for-it.sh may be the solution some people need.

Comment: That is absolutely correct and a bit of a shame that docker-compose doesn't support any fine grained control like waiting for a container to exit or start listening on a port. But yes, a custom script does solve this, good point!

Comment: This answer gives incorrect and potentially destructive information about how depends_on work.

Comment: If you are using alpine, you can use `apk add wait4ports` then use `wait4ports tcp://servicename:port` in your startup. No extra script needed. See https://github.com/erikogan/wait4ports.

Comment: Does this command set from docker compose file override the `CMD` defined in dockerfile ?

Comment: While technically correct [it works for `compose`], it won't work for compose files used for Docker Swarm [`stack deploy`].

Answer (score 182):

This works for me:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        python manage.py migrate
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - db
```

docker-compose tries to dereference variables *before* running the command, so if you want bash to handle variables you'll need to escape the dollar-signs by doubling them...

```yaml
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        var=$$(echo 'foo')
        echo $$var # prints foo
```

...otherwise you'll get an error:

> Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "web":

Comment: Hi, mate.
I met a problem:
```
unrecognized arguments: /bin/bash -c python3 /usr/local/airflow/__init__.py -C Local -T Windows
```
the command in my docker-compose.yml is:
command:
          - /bin/bash
          - -c
          - |
             python3 /usr/local/airflow/__init__.py -C ${Client} -T ${Types}
Do you know how to fix that? I add Client and Types in my .env file.

Comment: Here's a doc for you: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution I think what's happening is that your .env file places those variables in the container environment, but docker-compose is looking in your shell environment.  Try instead `$${Types}` and `$${Client}`.  I think this will prevent docker compose from interpreting those variables and looking for their values in whatever shell you invoke docker-compose from, which will mean that they're still around for bash to dereference them (_after_ docker has processed your `.env` file).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did what you said in fact. So I got the $(Client) in the error information. I changed the way to read environment variables to use os.getenv in python, which is easier. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't understand what the pipe ("|") operator thing does here. How does this work?

Comment: In this case the vertical bar is not a pipe (which is what bash would interpret it as), it's just YAML syntax for a multiline string literal: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#literal-style  both python commands get passed to bash as the second argument (after `-c`) and then bash interprets the newline as "run these as separate commands".

Comment: This is fancy, and neater than the one-liner (broken onto multiple lines) bash command chaining i was using. TY!

Comment: YAML has many fancy syntax tricks like this.  Think twice though: fancy YAML tends to confuse people who are reading your code.

Answer (score 119):

Cleanest ?

```
---
version: "2"
services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    command:
    - |
       echo a
       echo b
       echo c
```

Comment: This worked perfectly when the entrypoint of my image was other than sh/bash.

Comment: I don't understand what the pipe ("|") operator thing does here. How does this work?

Comment: @DerekMorrison: It's YAML syntax.  See https://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: for alpine, just this way work.

Answer (score 30):

You can use entrypoint here. entrypoint in docker is executed before the command while command is the default command that should be run when container starts.
So most of the applications generally carry setup procedure in entrypoint file and in the last they allow command to run.

make a shell script file may be as `docker-entrypoint.sh` (name does not matter) with following contents in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py migrate
exec "$@"
```

in docker-compose.yml file use it with `entrypoint: /docker-entrypoint.sh` and register command as `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
P.S : do not forget to copy `docker-entrypoint.sh` along with your code.

Comment: Note that this will execute also when you do `docker-compose run service-name ....`

Answer (score 23):

There are many great answers in this thread already, however, I found that a combination of a few of them seemed to work best, especially for Debian based users.

```
services:
  db:
    . . . 
  web:
    . . .
    depends_on:
       - "db"
    command: >      
      bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- python manage.py makemigrations
      && python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Prerequisites: add [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) to your project directory.

Warning from [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/): "(When using wait-for-it.sh) in production, your database could become unavailable or move hosts at any time ... (This solution is for people that) don’t need this level of resilience."

Edit:

This is a cool short term fix but for a long term solution you should try using entrypoints in the Dockerfiles for each image.

Answer (score 20):

Another idea:

If, as in this case, you build the container just place a startup script in it and run this with command. Or mount the startup script as volume.

Comment: Yes, at the end I created a run.sh script: ```#!/bin/bash \n

python manage.py migrate \n
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000``` (ugly oneline)

Answer (score 15):

*** UPDATE ***

I figured the best way to run some commands is to write a custom Dockerfile that does everything I want before the official CMD is ran from the image.

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'

# Can be used as an alternative to VBox/Vagrant
services:

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: deploy/local/Dockerfile.mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ../.data/mongodb:/data/db
```

**Dockerfile.mongo:**

```
FROM mongo:3.2.12

RUN mkdir -p /fixtures

COPY ./fixtures /fixtures

RUN (mongod --fork --syslog && \
     mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection clients --file /fixtures/clients.json && \
     mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection configs --file /fixtures/configs.json && \
     mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection content --file /fixtures/content.json && \
     mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection licenses --file /fixtures/licenses.json && \
     mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection lists --file /fixtures/lists.json && \
     mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection properties --file /fixtures/properties.json && \
     mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection videos --file /fixtures/videos.json)
```

This is probably the cleanest way to do it.

*** OLD WAY ***

I created a shell script with my commands. In this case I wanted to start `mongod`, and run `mongoimport` but calling `mongod` blocks you from running the rest.

**docker-compose.yaml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:3.2.12
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./fixtures:/fixtures
      - ./deploy:/deploy
      - ../.data/mongodb:/data/db
    command: sh /deploy/local/start_mongod.sh
```

**start_mongod.sh**:

```
mongod --fork --syslog && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection clients --file /fixtures/clients.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection configs --file /fixtures/configs.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection content --file /fixtures/content.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection licenses --file /fixtures/licenses.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection lists --file /fixtures/lists.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection properties --file /fixtures/properties.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection videos --file /fixtures/videos.json && \
pkill -f mongod && \
sleep 2 && \
mongod
```

So this forks mongo, does monogimport and then kills the forked mongo which is detached, and starts it up again without detaching. Not sure if there is a way to attach to a forked process but this does work.

NOTE: If you strictly want to load some initial db data this is the way to do it:

**mongo_import.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Import from fixtures

# Used in build and docker-compose mongo (different dirs)
DIRECTORY=../deploy/local/mongo_fixtures
if [[ -d "/fixtures" ]]; then
    DIRECTORY=/fixtures
fi
echo ${DIRECTORY}

mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection clients --file ${DIRECTORY}/clients.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection configs --file ${DIRECTORY}/configs.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection content --file ${DIRECTORY}/content.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection licenses --file ${DIRECTORY}/licenses.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection lists --file ${DIRECTORY}/lists.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection properties --file ${DIRECTORY}/properties.json && \
mongoimport --db wcm-local --collection videos --file ${DIRECTORY}/videos.json
```

mongo_fixtures/*.json files were created via mongoexport command.

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:3.2.12
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db:cached
      - ./deploy/local/mongo_fixtures:/fixtures
      - ./deploy/local/mongo_import.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo_import.sh


volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 12):

To run multiple commands in the docker-compose file by using **`bash -c`**.

```
command: >
    bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations
    && python manage.py migrate
    && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Source: https://intellipaat.com/community/19590/docker-run-multiple-commands-using-docker-compose-at-once?show=19597#a19597

Answer (score 12):

tht's my solution for this problem:

```
services:
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:4.4.4
    restart: always
#    OPTION 01:
#    command: >
#      bash -c "chmod +x /scripts/rs-init.sh
#      && sh /scripts/rs-init.sh"
#    OPTION 02:
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "chmod +x /scripts/rs-init.sh && sh /scripts/rs-init.sh"]
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    networks:
      - mongo-cluster
    volumes:
      - ~/mongors/data1:/data/db
      - ./rs-init.sh:/scripts/rs-init.sh
      - api_vol:/data/db
    environment:
      *env-vars
    depends_on:
      - mongo2
      - mongo3
```

Answer (score 6):

Alpine-based images actually seem to have no bash installed, but you can use `sh` or `ash` which link to `/bin/busybox`.

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:

  api:
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ash -c "flask models init && flask run"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to run more than one daemon process, there's a [suggestion in the Docker documentation to use Supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/) in an un-detached mode so all the sub-daemons will output to the stdout.

[From another SO question, I discovered you can redirect the child processes output to the stdout.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897796/918558)  That way you can see all the output!

Comment: Looking at this again, this answer seems more suited for running multiple commands in parallel instead of serially.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool such as wait-for-it or [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize). These are small wrapper scripts which you can include in your application’s image. Or write your own wrapper script to perform a more application-specific commands. according to: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: link to [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it). It should be noted (as it was in the docs you linked to) "The problem of waiting for a database (for example) to be ready is really just a subset of a much larger problem of distributed systems. In production, your database could become unavailable or move hosts at any time. Your application needs to be resilient to these types of failures." This solution is for people that "don’t need this level of resilience"

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Bjorn answer, docker has [recently introduced](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1290) special dependency rules that allows you to wait until the "init container" has exited successfully which gives

```yaml
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  image: app
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  depends_on:
    db:
    migration:
      condition: service_completed_successfully
migration:
  build: .
  image: app
  command: python manage.py migrate
  depends_on:
    - db
```

I'm not sure if you still need buildkit or not, but on my side it works with

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 1):

##### To run on Windows Container:

- Create `.bat` file (to run with cmd, or you can make a `.ps1` to run with powershell if your container have it)
- In the `command` or `entrypoint` use `myFile.bat` (or `myFile.ps1`)

Bellow my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  myservicename:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 
    container_name: mycontainername
    environment:
      - PORT=44390
    command: buildAndRun.bat
[...]
```

My `buildAndRun.bat`:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
dotnet build
dotnet run
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while trying to get my jenkins container set up to build docker containers as the jenkins user.

I needed to touch the docker.sock file in the Dockerfile as i link it later on in the docker-compose file.  Unless i touch'ed it first, it didn't yet exist.  This worked for me.

Dockerfile:

```
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; 
echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable" && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install docker-ce
RUN groupmod -g 492 docker && \
usermod -aG docker jenkins  && \
touch /var/run/docker.sock && \
chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

USER Jenkins
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
jenkins_pipeline:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "50083:50080"
    volumes:
        - /root/pipeline/jenkins/mount_point_home:/var/jenkins_home
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: This seems like the answer to different question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem where I wanted to run my react app on port 3000 and storybook on port 6006 both in the same containers.

I tried to start both as entrypoint commands from Dockerfile as well as using docker-compose `command` option.

After spending time on this, decided to separate these services into separate containers and it worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is trying to figure out multiple commands with *Windows* based containers the following format works:
`command: "cmd.exe /c call C:/Temp/script1.bat && dir && C:/Temp/script2.bat && ..."`

Including the 'call' directive was what fixed it for me.

Alternatively if each command can execute without previous commands succeeding, just separate each with semicolons:
`command: "cmd.exe /c call C:/Temp/script1.bat; dir; C:/Temp/script2.bat; ... "`

Answer (score -2):

If you need the first service to wait for the second one and not just start in order you can do a health check. Something like:

```
db:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres_test
  ports: "8000:8000"
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "5432"]
    interval: 5s
    timeout: 3s
    retries: 10 
web:
  build: .
  command: command1 && comand2
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    postgres_test:
      condition: service_healthy
```

This will make sure the second service is run only when the first service is health/reachable by definition of the self defined health check (so in this case as soon as 5432 is reachable on this service)

Comment: This misses the point of the original question; the OP is asking how to run multiple commands at the same time...simply using ampersands doesn't cut it. The "command" value is passed to the predefined entrypoint, which may or may not support ampersands. See the other answers and note how they mention "bash -c".

Comment: It was meant as an addition since the question was long answered. But i should have added this you are right.

Answer (score -8):

try using ";" to separate the commands if you are in verions two
e.g.

`command: "sleep 20; echo 'a'"`