# Why is my "docker-compose run" not working properly on windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, git-bash

So I am running a script that calls:

```
docker-compose run --rm web sh /data/bin/install_test_db.sh
```

and it seems to work fine when running it on ubuntu but when I run it on Windows using Git Bash I get this error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open C:/Program Files/Git/data/bin/install_test_db.sh
```

It seems to be trying to run the script on my machine and not the actual container from which I am trying to call it from.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try [passing a command to your sh shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064175/6309):

```
docker-compose run --rm web sh -c "/data/bin/install_test_db.sh"
```

Or:

```
docker-compose run --rm web "sh -c /data/bin/install_test_db.sh"
```

That will avoid your host shell (the git bash) to interpret an absolute path (starting with '`/`') as one from the Git installation path.

That will keep `/data/...` as an argument to be passed to the shell executed in the container.

---

Note: If you are using [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) (meaning *not* VirtualBox, but HyperV), you don't need `git bash` at all.

Try the same command from a regular CMD (with `docker.exe` in your `%PATH%`, which Docker for Windows set for you)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 C:\Users\vonc
> where docker
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe
```

If you need Linux-like commands from that same CMD session, then yes, add git paths:

```
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: I need to use git bash to run shell scripts unfortunately... and when I do your "sh -c" thing I get this as an error "sh: 1: C:/Program: not found"

Comment: @G3tinmybelly Can you try with double-quotes instead simple quotes?