# shell doesn't work in Docker

Tags: docker

I want to run shell.sh in Ubuntu docker with apache and some services. This is my shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/www/cron350.sh> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

So in docker-compose.yml I add this command:

```
command: bash -c "/var/www/shell.sh && service php7.1-fpm start && service cron start && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND"
```

I run "docker-compose up -d", however it doesn't work in the first time- everything is OK but the shell doesn't run. When I try to run "docker-compose up -d" again, the shell runs. Can you tell me why this happens? How can I fix it?

I'm so sorry because my English is not good.

Comment: Can you start it without `-d` and provide any errors from the log.

Comment: Thanks for your supporting. It doesn't work in the first time because cron350.sh connect to mysql container, however mysql container hasn't initialized at that time. I edited the shell and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of : [Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands/30064175#30064175)

To build docker container, `docker-compose up --build`

To start that, `docker start -t [CONTAINER]`

To execute an interactive bash shell on the container, `docker exec -it [CONTAINER_ID] bash`