# run java in docker-compose

Tags: java, mysql, sql, docker, docker-compose

this is my docker-compose file.yaml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: dbContainer
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
    - /home/crismon-01/Documenti/TESI/Docker/mysqlLogin/datas:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
    - 3306
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
     MYSQL_USER: "root"
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
     MYSQL_DATABASE: "schema1"
  java:
    container_name: loginJava
    image: openjdk:7
    depends_on:
    - db
    volumes:
    - ./home/crismon-01/Documenti/TESI/Docker/mysqlLogin:/usr/src/myapp 
    working_dir: /usr/src/myapp
    command: bash -c "java -jar LogiIn.jar"
```

it is a compose with two cotnainer one with mysql and one with javacode that use the db, now i need to run it, and i have this error:

```
crismon-01@crismon01-XPS15:~/Documenti/TESI/Docker/mysqlLogin$ docker-compose up
Starting dbContainer ... done
Starting mysqllogin_java_1 ... done
Attaching to dbContainer, mysqllogin_java_1
dbContainer | Initializing database
dbContainer | 2018-04-12T15:35:07.134004Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
dbContainer | 2018-04-12T15:35:07.135231Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
dbContainer | 2018-04-12T15:35:07.135247Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
dbContainer | 
java_1  | Error: Unable to access jarfile LogiIn.jar
dbContainer exited with code 1
mysqllogin_java_1 exited with code 1
```

could someone have idea of the dource of error?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are specifying `command` sections in the compose section of the java service. Only appears to be taken, which is the last one.

The solution is to group both commands into one command as such

```
java:
  image: openjdk:7
  depends_on:
  - db
  volumes:
  - /home/crismon-01/Documenti/TESI/Docker/mysqlLogin:/usr/src/myapp 
  command: bash -c "cd /usr/src/myapp && java -jar LogiIn.jar"
```

Take a look at [Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands) for more info.

Alternatively, you can only set `working_dir` property and remove the `cd` command.

```
  volumes:
  - /home/crismon-01/Documenti/TESI/Docker/mysqlLogin:/usr/src/myapp 
  working_dir: /usr/src/myapp
  command: java -jar LogiIn.jar
```

Comment: it say: 
starting container process caused "exec: \"cd\": executable file not found in $PATH":

like it don't see the folder in the container filesystem

Comment: @CristianMonti Updated  answer. Try wrapping the command using bash: `bash -c "cd /usr/src/myapp && java -jar LogiIn.jar"`. Alternatively use `working_dir` property.

Comment: i have this, could be the db?

Starting dbContainer ... done
Recreating mysqllogin_java_1 ... done
Attaching to dbContainer, mysqllogin_java_1
. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
dbContainer | 2018-04-12T15:53:25.475417Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
dbContainer | 2018-04-12T15:53:25.475433Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
dbContainer | 
dbContainer exited with code 1
mysqllogin_java_1 exited with code 1

Comment: > --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. 
 
The db is complaining that the data directory is not empty. This is due to the volume '/var/lib/mysql' already existing. Try cleaning the folder: `/home/crismon-01/Documenti/TESI/Docker/mysqlLogin` and then retry

Comment: yes, now it do some more stuff, but it close all:
dbContainer | 2018-04-12T16:06:57.332074Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
java_1  | Error: Unable to access jarfile LogiIn.jar
mysqllogin_java_1 exited with code 1
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

this is the error i see in the stacktrace of the shell

Answer (score 0):

Testcontainers library has support for Docker Compose

Quoting official documentation

> A single class rule, pointing to a docker-compose.yml file, should be sufficient to  launch any number of services required by your tests:

```
 @ClassRule public static DockerComposeContainer environment =
     new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/compose-test.yml"))
             .withExposedService("redis_1", REDIS_PORT)
             .withExposedService("elasticsearch_1", ELASTICSEARCH_PORT);
```

> In this example, compose-test.yml should have
> content such as:

```
redis:   image: redis elasticsearch:   image: elasticsearch
```

For more details see official documentation
https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/docker_compose/