# Problem to health check HAProxy docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, haproxy

HAProxy [image](https://store.docker.com/_/haproxy) comes with a really compact debian version, without ping, wget, curl or other commands to verify. How to use docker-compose health check for it, verifying that the HAProxy is up and running?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work:

echo "" > /dev/tcp/${HOSTNAME}/${PORT} || exit 1

which is using the /dev/tcp built-in with bash to test a connection to a port you know HAProxy should be running on, and will fail if cannot connect.

Comment: Just to add, you may have to run it within `bash` as the container's default shell is `sh`: `bash -c "echo '' > /dev/tcp/${HOSTNAME}/${PORT}"`

Answer (score 1):

You would configure a health check in the haproxy.cfg which you pass to the docker container. The health check portion could look like:

```
frontend frontend_name
  ...
  use_backend healthcheck if { path_beg /health }

backend healthcheck
  server disabled-server 127.0.0.1:1 disabled
  errorfile 503 /path/to/template.html
```

And the health check template file:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Cache-Control: no-cache

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/plain


up
```

How this works is that the health check backend, which you would route to from a frontend on whatever path you like /health for example. And instead of responding with a 503, the error file directive allows you to return a custom error response, in this case a 200.

Comment: Thank you, @jmoney
Just some questions:
1. Which is the format of the template file?
2. Where to set the /health path?

Comment: Also, how to call this URL, with no curl, for exemple?

Comment: 1. Updated the answer, it's html. 2. in the `frontend` section you'd add a `use_backend hhealthcheck if  { path_beg /health }` 3. Where are you trying to call the health url from? Another docker container? You could run one with curl on it, or call your haproxy health check from somewhere else?

Comment: 3. I am using docker-compose and this won't work, because the image doesn't contain curl, for example:
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:<port>/healthcheck || exit 1
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

Comment: Right, I'm not suggesting you run curl from your haproxy server, but rather from somewhere external to the container.

Comment: Or, if you're set on running it from the docker container, you could run commands via docker compose to install curl on the haproxy container. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands

Comment: Afaik you cannot return other codes than the one you are catching in haproxy. If you catch 503 then you can only return a 503 template.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@AdrianF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837674/1925616) above, I used the following:

In HAProxy's config, I added:

```
frontend health
  mode http
  bind 127.0.0.1:80
  http-request return status 200 if { src 127.0.0.0/8 }
```

Then, in the Compose file for HAProxy:

```
healthcheck:
  test: |
    bash -c 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/80; echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\nConnection: close\n" >&3; cat <&3 | grep -q "200 OK"'
```

Note: I had to use a heredoc here as a single line variant kept complaining of a YAML error, which I traced down to the colon after `Connection`.  There may be a way to escape that, but I couldn't figure it out.