# docker-compose run multiple commands for a service

Tags: docker

I am using docker on windows - version `18.03` (client)/`18.05` (server). I have created `docker-compose` file for ELK stack. Everything is working fine. What I would like to do is, to install [`logtrail`](https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail) before kibana is started. I was thinking about copying `logtrail*.zip` first, then call install:

```
container_name: kibana
(...)
command:
  - docker cp kibana:/ ./kibana/logtrail/logtrail-6.7.1-0.1.31.zip
  - /bin/bash
  - ./bin/kibana-plugin install/logtrail-6.7.1-0.1.31.zip
```

But that doesn't look like right way as first of all it doesn't work, second of all I am not sure if I can call mutliple commands like I did and third of all I'm not sure if `docker cp` in `command` is even allowed on that stage of service creation

Comment: Usually you want to create a custom image if you need to install software on top of some base image.

Answer (score 10):

```
command:
- /bin/bash
- -c
- |
  echo "This is a multiline command"
  echo "See how I escape $$ sign"
  echo $$PATH
```

You can run multiple commands like above however you can not run `docker cp` as in your command.

Answer (score 6):

You can run multiple commands for a service in docker compose by:

```sh
command: sh -c "command1 && command2 && command2"
```

Answer (score 1):

THATS MY SOLUTION FOR THIS CASE:

```
#    OPTION 01:
#    command: >
#      bash -c "chmod +x /scripts/rs-init.sh
#      && sh /scripts/rs-init.sh"
#    OPTION 02:
#    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "chmod +x /scripts/rs-init.sh && sh /scripts/rs-init.sh"]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to install software David Maze's comment seems to be the standard path. If you want to actually run multiple commands look at the answer to this SO question [Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands)