# Docker-compose multi-line command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I'm trying to figure out how to split a command to be on multiple lines in my docker-compose.yml file. The command is pretty long, and I would prefer to be able to see it without scrolling to the right in the file.

```
services:
  mysql:
    ...
    command: mysqld --character-sets-dir='/usr/share/mysql/charsets' --character-set-client-handshake=OFF --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4;'
```

Is there a way to split this into multiple lines that Docker will work with?

Comment: command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        do your job

Comment: Want to execute multiple command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands