# How to run multiple commands in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to read a bunch of environmental variables from a text file which exists in a docker image at address (/service/variables.txt) and set them as environmental variables in my running container and then execute a command which utilized them. I'm doing these steps in a docker-compose file as follows. I'd like my docker-compose to look like something like below.

```
services:
  service1:
    image: imagename:tag
    container_name: name
    command:
         - exec source /service/variables.txt
         - exec export $(cut -d= -f1 /service/variables.txt)
         - exec start_service $VAR1 $VAR2
```

My question is how can I have multiple `exec` command under `command` in a docker-file?

Comment: Is wrapping commands in a script an option for you?

Comment: You can wrap it into a shell script and run it as an ENTRYPOINT of a docker image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands)

Comment: So the script should be in a separate file and I include all 3 commands in there?

Comment: I put those commands in a script file (script.sh) which exist in the same directory as my docker-compose .yaml file but when running the docker-compose it says the script.sh does not exist, "stat source ./script.sh: no such file or directory"

Comment: @H.Z. You should copy script file during image build so it is available at runtime.