# bash command for runniung multiple commands in docker container

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I'm trying to set up a database with a table inside a docker container. For correct working of DB, I need to run the following command:

`--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`
*ps: I don't understand what this command exactly is for, but it prevents some strange logs by setting the DB up.*

For set up, I use docker-compose as follow:

```
db:
image: mysql
command: >
  bash -c "--init-file /pictureapi_mydb_response.sql
  && --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
volumes:
  - ./pictureapi_mydb_response.sql:/pictureapi_mydb_response.sql
restart: always
ports:
  - 3307:3306
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_MYSQL_PASS}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands)

I'm getting the following errors:

> bash: --: invalid option
> db_1       | Usage:     bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
> db_1       |    bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
> db_1       | GNU long options:
> db_1       |    --debug
> db_1       |    --debugger\

How should I actually run two or more commands if *"bash"* instruction doesn't work?

Comment: Are those actual commands, or options to `mysqld`?

Comment: @DavidMaze I suppose options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker Hub `mysql` image is configured so that, if the `command:` starts with `-`, the entire command is assumed to be `mysqld` startup options.  It's not actually "a command", and you can't use `bash` to run it.  If you need multiple startup options, just combine them together into a single `command:`:

```yaml
command: --init-file /pictureapi_mydb_response.sql --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

When you launch a Docker container, [its "entrypoint" and "command" parts are combined into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), so the command is passed as additional arguments to the entrypoint if both are present.  The most common pattern is that the command is a complete executable command on its own, but there's an alternate pattern where the entrypoint is (or provides) the main command to run and the command just provides extra options.

The Docker Hub `mysql` container has a rather involved [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/b0a0e546712534b30ac13e8b2829f23654facbc5/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh), but it eventually concludes with this logic:

```sh
# if command starts with an option, prepend mysqld
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- mysqld "$@"
fi
```

That is, if you run a container with

```yaml
command: --an-option-starting-with-minus
```

the actual command the container runs is `mysqld --an-option-starting-with-minus`.  So if you have multiple `mysqld` options you need to set, you can just pass them as the "command" and they'll get handled appropriately.