# Docker install and use composer with laravel and dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Im startig my journal with docker.

I made docker-compose.yml that starts following services:

- nginx
- PHP 8.1

I setup site to display and read php files, everything is ok. But right now I don't know whats next. I want to install laravel with composer and NPM. How to run it together in that way I can user "composer install", "composer update" in every project.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx_tst
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - php
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - "./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
      - "./:/usr/share/nginx/html"

  php:
    container_name: php_tst
    image: php:8.1-fpm
    networks:
      - php
    volumes:
      - "./:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    working_dir: /

networks:
  php:

Edit:

I Switched to Laravel Sail, it makes everything by itself
```

Comment: Do you tried to use command attribute as below answer and the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add command attribute to the php service. Using that you can execute compose install and update commands and etc...

Follow this link to know how to execute multiple commands

[Docker Compose - How to execute multiple commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands)

You can use something like this.

```
command: curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go inside the container

```
docker exec -it php_tst bash
```

and then install & run composer

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
php composer.phar install
```

install & run [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

nvm install node
node -v
npm i 
npm run dev
```

Comment: Is it good practice? What happen when I restart linux? Installation still will be there or I have to do this steps everytime I restart linux?

Comment: This is not a good practice; anything you do in this `docker exec` shell will get lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd suggest using `docker exec` sparingly: it's a very useful debugging tool but it shouldn't usually be part of your core workflow.

Comment: So how to use composer correctly on docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze for local developments it's totally ok, any suggestions on how to use it in the proper way?