# docker compose | cant run two command using '&&' in command property

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-command

I have a docker compose file and in the definition of one of my containers I try to run multiple commands, but when I run two commands one after another, the other command doesn't execute.
I tried changing the order between these two commands, and still every time the second command after the && does not run.
Does anyone have any idea what this could possibly be?

This is the docker container defenetion in the docker compose file:

```
  django:
    container_name: django
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: server:${SERVER_IMAGE_TAG}
    hostname: django
    command: /bin/bash -c "/tmp/startup.sh && echo 'export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.dev' >> /etc/apache2/envvars"
    ports:
      - "4443:443"
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
```

and a closer look at the command:

```
command: /bin/bash -c "/tmp/startup.sh && echo 'export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.dev' >> /etc/apache2/envvars"
```

it is important to say that both of the command works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose - How to execute multiple commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands)

Comment: Looks like `startup,sh` should have a dot somewhere =)

Comment: sorry @KlasŠ. I edited it, this was not the issue, I wrote here the command by hand so I had small problem. Can you address the issue with the dot in the right place? :)

Comment: @digby280 unforurtnetly it doesn't answer my question, I tried everything on this thread...

Comment: Is /tmp/startup.sh exiting with a non-zero?

Comment: yes, it is exiting with non-zero..

Comment: The _whole point_ of using `&&` instead of `;` is to abort if the thing on the left threw an error. Why are you using it if that's not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If `/tmp/startup.sh` exits with non-zero status ([as found out by *digby280*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75849797/docker-compose-cant-run-two-command-using-in-command-property?noredirect=1#comment133791857_75849797)), *bash* will not run second command after `&&`: see [List Constructs: Chaining](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF) for details.

Replace `&&` with `;` in your `bash -c "..."` command:

```
$ false
# `false` returns non-zero exit status
$ echo $?
1
$ false && echo "Won't run"
$ false ; echo "Will run!"
Will run!
```

Comment: hi. i'm facing the same issue. Trying to run `php-fmt` command and also a bash script to setup some stuff. Replaced `&&` by `;` but the result seems the same. My script seems to be exiting with non-zero status so my second command (`php-fmt`) is not running. Anything else I could try? Thanks